# How can I see the color labels when printing a board in Trello?

Tags: trello

When I print a board (either directly with Chrome print or with the "Print Board" option), the output shows no colors, even if the configuration of my printer is "Color".
I don't get colors in Preview nor in Print.

Is there a way to print the board with color labels?

Answer (score 4):

It's likely your browser's default setting not to print background. It saves on expensive printer ink.

You can change it though. If you select 'print backgrounds' in your browser's print dialog, it will include the background colors and icons.

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems relevant, as I just noticed that printing another site doesn't print the background image. However, I have troubles being able to change this setting, as the option doesn't appear in my printer settings, and forums show it would not be accessible on 64 bits. So I sent a mail to Canon support to ask how to access it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Kuzette - Printing background colours and images is a browser setting - not a setting on your printer preferences dialog. Firefox and IE have settings Print > Page Setup, but if you're using Chrome, it doesn't have this control although [it looks imminent](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2294)

Comment: @Bobby Grace - doesn't [this discussion](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113343) mean that Trello will need to explicitly add the -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact property if you want users to be able to print background colours and images on Chrome?